# adding button to android java code

Tags: java, android, xml, button

How can I add button into android java code? it is  main activity java code:

```
    package com.example.pafima_trial;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
        }

    }
```

It is  SingleTouchEventView.java

```
    public class SingleTouchEventView extends View {
      private Paint paint = new Paint();
      private Path path = new Path();
      boolean touched = false;
      float x =0;
      float y =0;
      float [] inputx = new float[200];
      float [] inputy = new float[200];
      String [] direction = new String [200];
      int count =0;
      int dcount =0;

      public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
          return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);

    touched=true;
          inputx[count]=eventX;
          inputy[count]=eventY;
          System.out.println("x is: "+ inputx[count]);
          System.out.println("y is: "+inputy[count]);
          if(count>=2 && count%2 != 1){

              if(inputx[count-2]-inputx[count]<=-15){
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]<=-15){
              direction[dcount]="right down";
              dcount++;
          }
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]>15){
              direction[dcount]="right up";
              dcount++;
          }
          if(-14<=inputy[count-2]-inputy[count] && inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]<=15 ){
              direction[dcount]="right";
              dcount++;
          }
      }

      if(inputx[count-2]-inputx[count]>15){
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]>=15){
              direction[dcount]="left up";
              dcount++;
          }
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]<-15){
              direction[dcount]="left down";
              dcount++;
          }
          if(15>inputy[count-2]-inputy[count] && inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]>=-15 ){
              direction[dcount]="left";
              dcount++;
          }
      }

      if (inputx[count-2]-inputx[count]<=15 && inputx[count-2]-inputx[count]>-15){
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]<-15){
              direction[dcount]="down";
              dcount++;
          }
          if(inputy[count-2]-inputy[count]>=15){
              direction[dcount]="up";
              dcount++;
          }

      }
  }
  count++;
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    System.out.println("count is "+count);
  break;
default:
  return false;
}
    int a =0;
    while(a<dcount){
        System.out.println("direction["+a+"] is: "+ direction[a]);

        a++;
    }
// Schedules a repaint.
invalidate();
return true;
      }


    }
```

I couldn't add boutton in main activity java code, I couldn't set activity main xml file as a content view.
Also can I give link to xml file in java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add another View in Main Activity layout using [getWindow().addContentView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) as:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));
    //add xml layout to Activity Window
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null),
                              new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

}
```

Comment: @romando90 : this is just comment for separating code which you also need to add with existing code

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the main_activity.xml as your content view, find the relativelayout by id and add by using realtivelayout.addView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null)).
Then You've got your xml file and your singletoucheventview.

In the xml file find Your RelativeLayout and add:

```
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
```

That's just an example.
After that go to Your class and create the Object:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
```

After that You'll be able to call

```
relativeLayout.addView(View);
```

Comment: How can I find relative layout using findViewbyId?

Answer (score 0):

SingleTouchEventView view= new SingleTouchEventView(this, null)

```
 setContentView(view);
 Button b = new Button(MainActivity.this);
 view.addView(b);
```